# Simple Maths Riddle 2

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.
>
> The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.
>
> A decimal you'll require; my anagram leads a choir.

What am I?

---

**HINT 1**

> For *not literally defined*, look at its actual symbol... if you get it you'll know what I mean :)

Comment: I have a question: is the FULL anagram of the word that leads the choir, right? Or just part of it?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire comments are volatile. Information in comments that can lead/change answers should be added to the question body. Please do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I may have solved my first one!!!

Is it

> Percent?

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> The word percent has a definition as a fraction of 100, but the symbol is 0/0 - which is undefined.

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.

> The symbol is two circles with a line between them

A decimal you'll require; my anagram leads a choir.

> Percents can often be expresses as decimal numbers, and...
> Definition of precent : intransitive verb : to act as precentor : lead a choir or congregation in singing

Comment: unfortunately @Cain was faster

Comment: Oh man! I'm just happy I got one. Next time I'll be faster with the formatting. Nice job @Cain. Although I think my answer for "not literally defined" is better.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are

> Percent

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> Percent has a meaning, but the symbol has no hard boundary, so is not literally defined.

The simplest of shapes, circles and lines.

> Self evident

A decimal you'll require

> Alternate form of a number in percent is as a decimal.

my anagram leads a choir

> Precent is the leader of a choir

Comment: If you look at the symbol (as per the hint) you will see it looks like an undefined math operation. I'm pretty sure that is the interpretation of "not literally defined". (Edit: I just noticed that EnderGC has already posted that.)

Answer (score 11):

My answer will be fast and loose, but I don't mean to be obtuse.

You are

> an *angle*.

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> You have a meaning within geometry, but literally you're just space.

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.

> Angles are commonly drawn with circles and lines, like with radians.

A decimal you'll require;

> The measurement of an angle doesn't usually require a decimal, but most numbers innately have them...? An angle does require a *point*, though.

my anagram leads a choir

> Anagram of angle is *angel*, which can lead a group of them called a choir.

Comment: (+1) Very good answer, though not the one I'm after! The 'decimal you'll require' is a bit hard to explain for an *angle*... and by *decimal* I don't mean its synonym *point* ;)

Comment: Aww, darn. This is gonna be one of those riddles where I'm going to slap myself once the answer's revealed, huh. xD

Comment: With that hint, now I have something, but it doesn't fit the last clue...

Comment: Can't you use Radians instead of degrees for an angle? You usually use decimals/fractions in radians.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> a point

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> you define it with coordinates but always depending on the context

The simplest of shapes, circles and lines.

> they're made from points

A decimal you'll require

> needed for making a decimal

my anagram leads a choir

> you can lead a choir with a pointer

Comment: How about the choir?

Comment: I keep searching that one.

Comment: here are a list of anagrams https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=point&t=500&a=n :D

Comment: it's the anagram of the word we are looking for that leads the choir, not the word itself

Comment: I really don't get that last one...

Comment: Good attempt! But unfortunately it is not the one I'm after... you can't rearrange the letters of 'point' into something that leads a choir...

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying, nothing. It could have worked if you said "my anagram leads a choice"... but not for a choir ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> cylinder

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> we can define a cylinder but we can't use an existing symbol to do so

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.

> two circles and infinite amount of lines perpendicular to their perimeter

A decimal you'll require

> $pi$

my anagram leads a choir

> lyric(s) can lead a choir

Comment: (+1) Great answer, though it's not the one I'm looking for. Also please see the comment below the original post about the *full* anagram (that uses all the words) :)

Comment: My bad, I missed the comment. I have no math background so this was my best shot. And I know you meant letters not words ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> ten or 10

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> 10 is defined as a natural number

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.

> I0

a decimal you require

> decimal numeral system is also called base-10 numeral system

my anagram leads a choir

> **Ten** in dirig**ent**

Comment: Good shot, though you have missed two other parts of the riddle!

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see it. You were talking about circles and lines in plural :)

Comment: No they can be singular ;)

Comment: And see the comment above that requires a *full* anagram :)

Comment: I will try another shot :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Radian

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined

> a unit of measurement of angles equal to about 57.3°

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines

> The length of an arc of a unit circle is numerically equal to the measurement in radians of the angle that it subtends

A decimal you'll require

> 1 Rad = 57.2958...°

my anagram leads a choir

> Aria. From rearranging particular letters from Radian. An Aria leading a choir during an operatic performance.

Comment: I'm confused - could you explain how your answer for the last line is an anagram of the overall answer?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, and thanks for posting an answer! You've got some of the parts right, but how can you rearrange the letters of *radian* to give *prima donna*? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> $tangent$

I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.

> Tangent has a definition of how to calculate and how to get it, but it's not a defined function itself.

The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.

> Tangent can be represented as a line segment tangent to the circle

A decimal you'll require;

> Not sure, but maybe because a circle needs a $pi$?

my anagram leads a choir

> A conductor can lead a choir with a baton. baton anagram could be $tan$, but I think you want it the other way around. Thinking about it.

Comment: Nope, but good try!

Comment: I need to learn more english :p

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> **Infinity** $\infty$

`I have a definition, but I'm not literally defined.`

> Infinity is a concept or idea of never-ending and having no limits — it is **not** defined as a number.

`The simplest of shapes: circles and lines.`

> $$\text{It is simple, like drawing a sideways $8$.}$$ [image: Infinity]

`A decimal you'll require;`

> Ways of mathematically expressing infinity include initiating a divergent series like $(1)$ or converting certain fractions to **decimals** like $(2)$. $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1i &=\infty\tag1 \\ \frac 13&=0.\underbrace{3333333333\ldots}_{\text{infinite times}}\tag2\end{align}$$

`My anagram leads a choir.`

> Infinity is also known as a *figure eight*, which has an anagram of **three**, and three lead a choir (the Conductor, with their hand and face gestures; their baton; and the song of choice).

Comment: (+1) Very good try! The last two are pushing it slightly though ;)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire hahah, yes they were indeed the hardest. Great riddle, though :))